# Terminal services: can't connect to remote computer

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-terminal-services

I am sometimes getting the following error when attempting to RDP to another machine on a LAN:

[image]

What is the likely cause of this?

It only happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you determined basic network connection diagnostics when you get a failure?
Such as the ability to ping the name of the device?
Or another key diagnostic is trying to initiate a connection via IP address.

Is this a Windows to Windows connection attempt?

.am

Comment: Yes. XP to XP. Whenever the problem occurs, an immediate re-attempt will be successful.

Comment: ok. but did you mean you are consistently using the name to connect and the first connection is rejected then you simply try again without closing the mstsc app and then it works?

Comment: The computer name is used to connect.  It is not always the first connection that is rejected.  I cannot determine any pattern to it.